#  updating a TextView from another concurrent View

Tags: android, textview, android-view

So this one is probably very simple, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

So I have a custom View, which is now running in an activity along with a standard TextView widget.

What I want to know is whether there is a way to update the TextView from my custom View class

Comment: same activity? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a listener interface in the custom view. Define a `setXxxListener()` method in the view. Override the listener in the activity class. From the custom view, call the listener when needed. In the activity's listener implementation, update the TextView.

Such is the Java way.

In general, view classes should not make assumptions about other views running along. The object that manages both views - in your case the activity - should coordinate the data exchange between them.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Can you give me an example of how that works in general? Maybe a good link?

Comment: Please describe your custom view and tell us what kind of events in it should update the TextView.